# how to check which button is clicked and show result in onActivityResult in same activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

> What i am trying to do is that i want to display image in two different imageview but i am not able to set the selected image for particular image view right now i have two image view and two button... here is my code

**this is my buttons**

```
 setImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagePicker.pickImage(ScrollingActivity.this, "Select your image:");
        }
    });

    setImage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagePicker.pickImage(ScrollingActivity.this, "Select your image:");

        }
    });
```

**here i am displaying the image but image shows only in profileimage**

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    bitmap = imagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Now image is not displaying 
    if (requestCode == imageSelect) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            setImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } else if (requestCode == imageSelect2) {
        if (bitmap != null) {

            profileImage2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            // setImage2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    InputStream is = imagePicker.getInputStreamFromResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (is != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Got input stream!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to get input stream!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I just set the request code to each button**

```
setImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagePicker.pickImage(ScrollingActivity.this, 1);
        }
    });

    setImage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imagePicker.pickImage(ScrollingActivity.this, 2);

        }
    });
```

**And just use "If else" in onActivity**

```
  if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            setImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } else if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (bitmap != null) {

            profileImage2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            // setImage2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to give different `requestCode` for both the image and handle based on that in `onActivityResult()`

Add one more param in you `imagePicker.pickImage`

Instead of:

```
public void pickImage(Activity activity, String value)
```

change to:

```
public void pickImage(Activity activity, String value, int requestCode)
```

give different request code for each image. So that based on request code you can do action in `onActivityResult()`

In your `onActivityResult()` you should check the request code for the first image too

```
if (bitmap != null  ) {
    if(requestCode == imageSelect1) {

        profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        profileImage2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the latest code you have.

Comment: And also in your first **if statement** you should check with first requestCode

Comment: this is my updated coded  and i am using com.mvc.imagepicker.ImagePicker this library so i can add one param in public void(Activity activity, String value)

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/Mariovc/ImagePicker/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mvc/imagepicker/ImagePicker.java) they have already method for that to send the request code, **public static void pickImage(Activity activity, String chooserTitle,
                                 int requestCode, boolean galleryOnly)** you can use this method

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to overcome your problem.
first:
set tags for your buttons in your layout xml properties and you can get those tags by using followin:

```
button.getTag();
```

it will return your entered tag in xml view properties.

second:
you can add another argument to your onActivityResult function that it's value specifies which button had been clicked.

Comment: can you please elaborate i still don't get you sir... give example